# Where to handle side effect in redux?

Tags: redux

I am writing a simple login page.

After user clicks on login button, I will be receiving a user authentication token if the login is successful.

I would like to store the token in to a simple sqlite storage.

Where should I put this logic? (The async opening db, updating db logic), I am currently putting them in the action creators for the SUCCESS_LOGIN action. But what does redux recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle side effects in react/redux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755941/how-to-handle-side-effects-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple questions like this one:

[How to handle complex side-effects in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925837/how-to-handle-complex-side-effects-in-redux)

[How to handle side effects in react/redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755941/how-to-handle-side-effects-in-react-redux)

Personally I use [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga), but [redux-loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop) is also very popular.

If it's a simple application you could use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or you are probably ok with your current approach, no need to add more libraries and boilerplate if you have all the functionality done.

Comment: Cool I think i'll stick with redux-thunk for now. Will look at redux-saga when there are more side effects going on i guess.